# How to show special character in UTF-8 of Kmer symbol

Tags: html, css, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

I have got ឴symbol, that i can't display on web page (utf-8) content type. This symbol without width and can't see at all. How to show it? Code is `&#6068;`

for example here http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/khmer.php 6068 and 6069 are not visible, but i need to show it, at least space

**Edited:** 
I'm using Arial or sans-serif. I think, that it is pretty usual fonts. What people do: they making UNIQUE text by inserting this symbol inside usual symbols. For example, user write: "a(invisible symbol of kmer)b(invisible symbol of kmer)" and so on. I see on page only "ab" without any spaces. I tried to put actual character inside html to see it, but with no luck. I thought that symbol, that is not present in font should be question mark or empty square, but not in that case. Solution can't just be simple replace in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your page is UTF-8 then it's better to use the actual character rather than a HTML entity.

Your requested character is not present in many fonts. You can try finding the latest version of Code2000 which appears to support it.

You can see fonts that support this particular character here:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/17b4/fontsupport.htm

If you can't find a font and you want to display an empty space instead you could replace it before showing it in the page or put it in a container. The page you linked uses a table cell to hold the character.

Comment: it is not that symbol, that i wrote. you entered ``&#6067;`` problem is that users entered symbol 6068 that is not visible on page, but is should be at least space

Comment: Updated taking into account the correct character code `0x17b4`

Comment: I'm using Arial or sans-serif. I think, that it is pretty usual fonts. What people do: they making UNIQUE text by inserting this symbol inside usual symbols. For example, user write:  "a(invisible symbol of kmer)b(invisible symbol of kmer)" and so on. I see on page only "ab" without any spaces. I tried to put actual character inside html to see it, but with no luck. I thought that symbol, that is not present in font should be question mark or empty square, but not in that case